# $P,Q$ is any two subset of $(X,d)$ with $P\subset Q$, then what is the value of $\sup\limits_{x\in P} \inf\limits_{y\in Q} d(x,y)$?

Tags: metric-spaces, intuition, hausdorff-distance, gromov-hausdorff-limit

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space. Then the function $d_H:\mathcal P(X)\times\mathcal P(X)\to\mathcal [0,\infty]$ defined by $$d_H(A,B)= \max \{ \sup\limits_{x\in A} \inf\limits_{y\in B} d(x,y), \  \sup\limits_{y\in B} \inf\limits_{x\in A} d(x,y) \}$$ for all $A,B\subset X$. This $d_H$ is called [Hausdorff distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausdorff_distance).

Now I want to check $d_H (A,B)$ for some particular case.

Consider the metric space $(\mathbb R^2,d)$ with euclidean metric $d$. Let $B=\{(x,y):x^2+y^2\leq16 \}$ and $A=\{(x,y):(x+2)^2+y^2\leq1 \}$ two subsets of  $\mathbb R^2$. Here $A\subset B$. Then I have checked that first part of the definition of $d_H$ is $0$ and second part is $5$. Thus $d_H (A,B)$ is equal to $5$, being the maximum of $0,5$. Am I wrong?

I am confused because of this [figure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausdorff_distance#/media/File:Hausdorff_distance_sample.svg) in Wikipedia.

**My question** is if $P,Q$ is any two subset of $(X,d)$ with $P\subset Q$, then is it true that $\sup\limits_{x\in P} \inf\limits_{y\in Q} d(x,y)=0$?

Comment: Small nit-pick: it's $d_H:\mathcal P(X)^2\to\mathcal [0,\infty]$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First question: I think your answer is correct. $d_H(A,B)=5$.

Second question. YES, again. If $x \in P$ then $x \in Q$ so $\inf_{y \in Q} d(x,y)\leq d(x,x)=0$. Take sup over $x$.

Comment: Then I believe that the above mentioned figure from Wikipedia is actually wrong. @Murthy sir, have you seen it?

Comment: @BijanDatta Yes, the figure is wrong.

Comment: @BijanDatta I don't really follow what you mean by saying that the figure is "wrong". I don't see anywhere in that Wikipedia article the claim that $d_H$ is zero in that picture. Moreover, the picture displays distance between two sets neither of which is a subset of the other one. (The [current revision](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Hausdorff_distance&oldid=877749743) says in the caption of the figure: "Components of the calculation of the Hausdorff distance between the green line $X$ and the blue line $Y$."

Comment: Actually it seems from the picture that the two sets are in the situation that one is contained in another (though it is not written in Wikipedia for this picture). Then the length of one line(among blue and green) should be zero. So the picture is wrong in that sense what I've meant here. I know this was a stupid concept to claim.